# Unable to parse Magento soap api response in Android

Tags: java, android, magento, soap, xml-parsing

I implement ksoap2 api in my android app for calling Magento Soap API, I got session id successfully, I'm getting response of category listing. I got repose like

```
<callReturn xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">category_id</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">parent_id</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">name</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Root Catalog</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">is_active</key>
                <value xsi:nil="true"/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">position</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">image</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">meta_title</key>
                <value xsi:nil="true"/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">meta_keywords</key>
                <value xsi:nil="true"/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">level</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">children</key>
                <value SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                    <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                        <item>
                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">category_id</key>
                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2</value>
```

The issue is I'm unable to parse this soap response in android object or Arraylist.

Comment: Please expand; *why* are you unable to parse this?

Comment: Don't know how to parse such type of responce.. like <Item> has childrens which has same property name..

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this github link of my android application which uses Magento SOAP api . and I have parsed it and i displayed .

https://github.com/sudhirbelagali/SnowDogSoapAndroid

this app gives you session id from magento SOAP protocol

Below is the code for parsing the output of ProductList .refere this

```
  SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) env.bodyIn;

        Log.d("resultRequestSOAP ", resultRequestSOAP.toString());

        SoapObject s_deals = (SoapObject) resultRequestSOAP.getProperty("storeView");

        for (int i = 0; i < s_deals.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            Object property = s_deals.getProperty(i);
            if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
                SoapObject category_list = (SoapObject) property;
                String CATEGORY = category_list.getProperty("product_id").toString();

                list_Prod_id.add(CATEGORY);

                String CATEGORY_URL = category_list.getProperty("sku").toString();

                // list.add(CATEGORY_URL);

                String CATEGORY_ICON = category_list.getProperty("name").toString();

                list_Prod_id.add(CATEGORY_ICON);
                list_Prod_id.add("*");


                String CATEGORY_COUNT = category_list.getProperty("set").toString();

                //list.add(CATEGORY_COUNT);

                String SUPERTAG = category_list.getProperty("type").toString();


            }
        }
        Log.d("List of Product id's ", String.valueOf(list_Prod_id));
```